# FB.api() not firing callback when accessed on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple Web app that uses the FB Javascript SDK to make a few Graph calls. It's natively embedded (via Javascript, not iFrames) in a third-party page whose code I cannot modify.

The host page already loads the Facebook SDK script (all.js) in order to implement share buttons. However, I need to call `FB.login()` again since my app requires `read_stream` permissions, which the main page does not. This apparently means I have to reinitialize the SDK, which is not ideal. I can't seem to avoid the "You've run init twice" warning.

What's strange is that the app works in a regular browser *but not on the iPhone* (either on a physical iPhone or in Safari on my Mac mimicking a iOS 6 User Agent.) The regular Safari UA works fine.

The following code calls my app via `callback`. On the iPhone, the anonymous callback fed to `FB.login` simply never fires (no error or anything).

```
    FB.init({
      appId      : appID,                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    }); 

    FB.login(function(response){
        FB.api("/me", "get", function(resp) {
            console.log("it works!", resp);
            callback(resp);
        });
    }, {scope: 'read_stream' });
```

What difference could an iOS user agent be making here? I'm really stumped.

Comment: Is the debug console enabled in the settings for Safari on the iPhone?

Comment: It is. I get a warning that "FB.init() ran twice," as mentioned, but no errors. It's as if FB.api() never runs. If I remove the init() call, though, I get "FB.login() called before FB.init()." Can't win!

Comment: You shouldn't have to call FB.init twice. Are you using an async init function like this `window.fbAsyncInit = function() { FB.init(); };`. FB.login can cause a popup window to open and Safari on the iPhone has a blocker - is the FB.login being run from a user interaction (e.g. button click) or just when they arrive at the page?

Comment: Strange that it stops working when you just switch the UA in the desktop safari. Humm....

Comment: It's very strange. I think the FB code on the host site is not well implemented. Sadly, I have no control over that. I wish I could somehow start over with the FB api.